# POST Request with JSON or HTML?

Tags: html, json, http, post

I want to make a POST request in order to get a list of "comments" back. The following post request is the one in question: 
http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_morechildren

now I'm a bit confused... 
First: am I sending my post request in JSON or as HTML? 
Second: the response I get is an HTML doc, but not correct.

This is what I have thus far to build the POST request:

```
public static void moreCommentsPostRequest(MoreComment c, String postId)
            throws IOException, JSONException {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.reddit.com/api/morechildren");

        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JSONStringer vm;

        vm = new JSONStringer().object().key("api_type").value("json")
                .key("children").value(childrenCSV).key("link_id")
                .value(postId).endObject();

        StringEntity httpPostEntity = new StringEntity(vm.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(httpPostEntity);

        // Execute and get the response.
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(instream, writer, "UTF-8");
                String theString = writer.toString();
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

The response I get back:

```
03-11 01:55:45.140: I/running(20225): response: <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
   <head>
      <title>reddit.com: forbidden (reddit.com)</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content=" reddit, reddit.com, vote, comment, submit " />
      <meta name="description" content="reddit: the front page of the internet" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
      <link rel='icon' href="http://www.redditstatic.com/icon.png" sizes="256x256" type="image/png" />
      <link rel='shortcut icon' href="http://www.redditstatic.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' href="http://www.redditstatic.com/icon-touch.png" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.redditstatic.com/reddit.tbeSemFBRCM.css" media="all">
      <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.redditstatic.com/reddit-ie6-hax.nzvIdaFFlC8.css" type="text/css" />
      <![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.redditstatic.com/reddit-ie7-hax.372dzeWThpM.css" type="text/css" />
      <![endif]--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.redditstatic.com/reddit-init.en.TdpFk8-t9Z8.js"></script><!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.redditstatic.com/html5shiv.n0ysDxgy3AI.js"></script><![endif]--><script type="text/javascript" id="config">r.setup({"ajax_domain": "www.reddit.com", "server_time": 1394520945.0, "post_site": "", "clicktracker_url": "//pixel.redditmedia.com/click", "logged": false, "cur_domain": "reddit.com", "gold": false, "is_fake": true, "renderstyle": "html", "over_18": false, "vote_hash": "", "adtracker_url": "//pixel.redditmedia.com/pixel/of_doom.png", "uitracker_url": "//pixel.redditmedia.com/pixel/of_discovery.png", "fetch_trackers_url": "//tracker.redditmedia.com/fetch-trackers", "modhash": false, "store_visits": false, "send_logs": true, "https_endpoint": "https://ssl.reddit.com", "extension": "", "static_root": "http://www.redditstatic.com", "status_msg": {"fetching": "fetching title...", "loading": "loading...", "submitting": "submitting..."}, "debug": false})</script><script type="text/javascript">reddit.cur_site = "t5_6";</script>
      <style type="text/css">/* Custom css: use this block to insert special translation-dependent css in the page header */</style>
   </head>
   <body class="" >
      <div id="header" role="banner">
      <a tabindex="1" href="#content" id="jumpToContent">jump to content</a>
      <div id="sr-header-area">
      <div class="width-clip">
      <div class="dropdown srdrop " onclick="open_menu(this)" onmouseover="hover_open_menu(this)"><span class="selected title">my subreddits</span></div>
      <div class="drop-choices srdrop ">
      <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals/" class="choice " >AdviceAnimals</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/" class="choice " >announcements</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/" class="choice " >AskReddit</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/" class="choice " >askscience</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/" class="choice " >aww</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/bestof/" class="choice " >bestof</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/blog/" class="choice " >blog</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/books/" class="choice " >books</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/" class="choice " >EarthPorn</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/" class="choice " >explainlikeimfive</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/" class="choice " >funny</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/" class="choice " >gaming</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/" class="choice " >gifs</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/" class="choice " >IAmA</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/movies/" class="choice " >movies</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/Music/" class="choice " >Music</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/news/" class="choice " >news</a><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/" class="choice " >pics</a><a href="
```

Comment: Why are you replacing all the "[" ? Also could post the output that you are getting?(You can mask it if you want)

Comment: ill add those back in. I have updated the post with the response I get back.